# Learning SharePoint Infrastructure

Tags: infrastructure

Im learning SP and i would be so glad, if you could help me. I got a couple of questions, so if you please could answer them and teach me.

1)How does AD DS work together with SP? Is it only because, you can create your users and groups, is that true?

2)What does .NET have to do with SP? Is it only because, you can deploy your own applications, is that true?

3)How does IIS work together with SP? When you are using central administration, you are actually configuring your IIS, is that true?

4)How does SQL server work together with SP? What kind of information is being recorded?

5)I believe the most importent infrastructure parts are, .NET, AD DS, IIS and SQL server. Is there anything else? As i said, im just learning, so if i missed anything, please let me know.

Thanks for your time and help. God bless.

Answer (score 0):

1) AD DS is the default authentication provider for SharePoint. Basically you create and manage your users in AD. Then the user can log on to his computer and sign into SharePoint. You could add different Identity Providers - so no, not only.

2) No, SharePoint is a ASP.Net application. This requires the .NET Framework. The SharePoint installer installs the required framework for you.

3) IIS hosts the SharePoint Application - because, as said in 2) its a ASP.Net application.

4) Wide question. Most of the data and configuration is stored in the SQL-Server.

5) Thats a good start. You forgot Windows Server and SharePoint itself. If all those parts work together then SharePoint is very performant and a great product.